# gradle.properties in android studio project missing

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-import

I imported android application from eclipse to android studio,Application working fine but **gradle.properties** is missing.

I need to integrate Uber SDK to my application,I need add following properties
UBER_CLIENT_ID,
UBER_REDIRECT_URI,
UBER_SERVER_TOKEN,

to **gradle.properties**,But there is no **gradle.properties**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the gradle.properties file inside the **root** of your project or inside the ~/home/user/.gradle/ folder

if you are in mac, type below command in the terminal:

```
cd ~/home/user/.gradle/
nano gradle.properties
```

And then type below in the opened file:

```
UBER_CLIENT_ID = "abc"
UBER_REDIRECT_URI = "bcd"
UBER_SERVER_TOKEN = "cde"
```